# Maven Multi-module projects with SVN

Tags: eclipse, svn, maven

I have a Maven multi-module project (one parent project with three children). The parents packaging is set to POM.

The issue is SVN wont check in the source code of the child projects (only their pom.xml files). Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Do you have problems during the build or working with SVN ? How is the project organized (folder structure etc.) ?

Comment: Nope - all works perfectly and SVN is fine. The parent project has a folder for each of the projects. Each project has a java source folder with packages within.

Comment: How are you trying check in the source code with Subversion?  Automated tool?  Command Line?  TortoiseSVN?  Maven?  If Maven, what command are you using?

Comment: I am using Subclipse to check the code in directly through Eclipse.

Comment: Have you added the sub folders via Subclipse ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:
first, checkout your parent project, which includes its several children project folders;
after checkout is finished, "File"->"Import"->"Existing Maven Projects", and select the parent project into "Root Directory", you'll see the children project in the "Projects" diagram,
then just select the ones as you want!

Comment: Does anybody know whether there is now a better way to achieve this?